# Parent div not the same width as child div

Tags: html, css

If I have a parent `<div>` with no width specified, and child `<div>` with a fixed width specified, and the window is smaller than the fixed width... **what rules within CSS/HTML result in the parent `<div>` only being the width of the window rather than the fixed width of the child?**

Using the following snippet, the parent has a background colour of red... and the child is way bigger than the window it's living in.

If you run the snippet and scroll the window to the right, you'll see that the red background of the parent is only as wide as the window itself, despite the child being a lot bigger?

```css
#parent {
   background-color:red;
}
#child {
   width:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"><div id="child">Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world</div></div>
```

Is there an easy CSS command that means that the parent has to be at least the same size as the child, without specifically setting the size with something like `min-width:1000px`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default `div` elements have `display: block` so their width is equal to width of its parent or in this case `body` or `html`.

But if you set `display` to `inline-block` on `#parent` element now that element will have width same as width of its content or largest child element in this case its `#child` element.

```css
#parent {
   background-color:red;
   display: inline-block;
}
#child {
   width:1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"><div id="child">Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Nenad... that's worked nicely. [Edit, thanks for the edit, now I understand]

Answer (score 2):

This might be solution which you are looking for:

```
#parent{
    background-color : red;
    display : inline-block;
}
#child {
   width:1000px;
}
```

or use the float:

```
#parent{
    background-color : red;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
#child {
   width:1000px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/powaznypowazny/pen/eWYNZE

Comment: Don't mix float with display. Simply float will remove display behavior, so in your example you can use only inline-block or only float, but both at same time is incorrect.

Comment: Looks like the `inline-block` is the way forward - thanks for your answer